# How to select a certain portion of a piecewise function?

Tags: piecewise

For example, if I have `Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]`, how do I select only the function that is for `x < 0`?  I want to set a new function equal to the `x^2` only, not the entire piecewise function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may know, `Part` (`[[  ]]`) works on non-lists as well. So, you can index your `Piecewise` like so:

```
Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}][[1, 1, 1]]
```

> x^2

With `Cases` you can pick out the part with a specific condition:

```
Cases[Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], {a_, x < 0} -> a, {2}] // First
```

> x^2

Answer (score 7):

You can use, for example

```
Refine[Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], x < 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @'Sjoerd C. de Vries', you can use

```
 P= Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]
 P[[1,1,1]]
 P[[1,2,1]]
```

For the first and select left elements. Surprisingly, if you wanted the third however,      `P[[1,3,1]]` won't work, and you will need instead:

```
 P[[2]]
```

This was actually discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126536/piecewise-function-extraction?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[pwPick]
pwPick = Module[{fpw = Internal`FromPiecewise @ #, cond = #2}, 
   First @ Pick[fpw[[2]], # === cond & /@ fpw[[1]]]] &
```

Examples:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}];
pwPick[pw, x < 0]
```

> x^2

```
pwPick[pw, x > 0]
```

> x

```
pwPick[pw, True]
```

> 0