# Selecting only list of function output from piecewise function output

Tags: piecewise, output

Say I have a piecewise function:

```
V[m_] := Piecewise[{{(1 + m)^2, m >= 1}, {Log[m], m < 1}}]
```

And I input a large list of `m` values, I get three lists output: The list of `V[m]` values, the list of `m` values for which `m >= 1`, and the list of `m` values for which `m < 1`.

I only require an output list of the `V[m]` values. How do I get rid of the other two lists?

Apologies if this is an obvious question! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not understanding the issue here. `V /@ {1, 10, 200, 0.1, 100}` outputs `{4, 121, 40401, -2.30259, 10201}`.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a certain portion of a piecewise function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36681/how-to-select-a-certain-portion-of-a-piecewise-function)

Comment: Ah - many apologies. I was incorrectly calling the function V - thank you @Mr.Wizard for solving.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: You can have `V` evaluate lists the way you were expecting it to. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

With the definition you have given, `V` isn't set up to thread over lists, which is what you seem to expect it to do. You can make that work that easy enough by giving it the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute.

```
SetAttributes[V, Listable]
V[m_] := Piecewise[{{(1 + m)^2, m >= 1}, {Log[m], m < 1}}]

SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[4, 10]
```

> `{1.70362, 1.56409, 1.38828, 1.81496, 2.22385, 1.15668, 1.18739, 0.825631, 
>   1.30068, 3.8933}`

Now,

```
V[data]
```

gives

> `{7.30957, 6.57457, 5.70387, 7.92401, 10.3932, 4.65126, 4.78468, -0.191608, 
>   5.29312, 23.9444}`

It will still work as it did originally if given a single value.

```
V[10]
```

> `121`